# pip: install a package from a github source subdirectory

Tags: github, pip

I am trying to install a Python package from a source directory in [a github repo](https://github.com/adamatan/github-packages-python). With accordance to the [Python Packaging Manual](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#configuring-metadata), The source directory contains a `setup.cfg` instead of the old `setup.py`.

## Code

My code follows the [Python Packaging Tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) - a parent directory which contains the metadata, and a `src` subdirectory which contains a sub-subdirectory with the package itself with and `__init__.py` file. It's available on https://github.com/adamatan/github-packages-python.

Installing locally - either by building a local `dist` and `wheel` using `python -m build`, and installing the `wheel` with `pip install <path_to_wheel>`, or by installing the source using `pip install packaging_tutorial - works well.

```sh
.
├── Dockerfile
├── LICENSE
├── Makefile
├── README.md
└── packaging_tutorial
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── README.md
    ├── build_and_publish.sh
    ├── pyproject.toml
    ├── setup.cfg
    └── src
        └── example_package
            ├── __init__py
            └── example.py
```

## What Have I Tried

### SSH Install

```sh
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/adamatan/github-packages-python.git#egg=packaging_tutorial

Collecting packaging_tutorial
  Cloning ssh://****@github.com/adamatan/github-packages-python.git to /private/var/folders/ty/43hxrncx4nl9n34kmq3w84300000gn/T/pip-install-oc4il6j7/packaging-tutorial_8d95646df03e40dab7f341209c8e71f5
  Running command git clone -q 'ssh://****@github.com/adamatan/github-packages-python.git' /private/var/folders/ty/43hxrncx4nl9n34kmq3w84300000gn/T/pip-install-oc4il6j7/packaging-tutorial_8d95646df03e40dab7f341209c8e71f5
ERROR: File "setup.py" not found for legacy project packaging_tutorial from git+ssh://****@github.com/adamatan/github-packages-python.git#egg=packaging_tutorial.
```

### HTTPS install

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/adamatan/github-packages-python.git#egg=packaging_tutorial
Collecting packaging_tutorial
  Cloning https://github.com/adamatan/github-packages-python.git to /private/var/folders/ty/43hxrncx4nl9n34kmq3w84300000gn/T/pip-install-sgke7nr1/packaging-tutorial_61f519a8caca48cea01fe22fd5438936
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/adamatan/github-packages-python.git /private/var/folders/ty/43hxrncx4nl9n34kmq3w84300000gn/T/pip-install-sgke7nr1/packaging-tutorial_61f519a8caca48cea01fe22fd5438936
ERROR: File "setup.py" not found for legacy project packaging_tutorial from git+https://github.com/adamatan/github-packages-python.git#egg=packaging_tutorial.
```

## My Question

How can I install the `example_package` package from its source on Github?

Comment: Note: Git is just an underlying transport/retrieval system here, and not involved in the actual answer. (Even GItHub isn't really relevant, it's just the storage location. The whole thing is a pip issue.)

Answer (score 4):

The solution is simple - I just had to use the `subdirectory` flag instead (or in addition to) the `egg` one.

So:

```sh
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/adamatan/github-packages-python.git#subdirectory=packaging_tutorial

pip install git+https://github.com/adamatan/github-packages-python.git#subdirectory=packaging_tutorial
```

Or:

```sh
pip install "git+ssh://git@github.com/adamatan/github-packages-python.git#subdirectory=packaging_tutorial&egg=example-pkg-adamatan"
```

Quoting [the manual](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/#url-fragments):

> pip looks at 2 fragments for VCS URLs:
>
> egg: For specifying the “project name” for use in pip’s dependency
> resolution logic. eg: egg=project_name
>
> subdirectory: For specifying the path to the Python package, when it
> is not in the root of the VCS directory. eg: pkg_dir

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer on your own question, since it helped me today as well! Maybe you can mark it as "accepted answer" to help future readers?

Comment: why not check that green arrow to accept your own answer?